# mp4 encoding used by Google Video?

Tags: video, encoding, mp4, codec

I have an HTC Touch HD on which mp4 videos downloaded from Google Video play the best, both in terms of video and audio quality. 
So I am wondering which settings exactly Google Video uses to encode videos into mp4, so that I can replicate it for videos not available on Google Video. A tool which reads an mp4 file and tells you all the encoding information would be perfect or if you know a official website that describes Google Video's mp4 format, then even better.

I am looking for the following information:

**Video Encoding**

- video resolution (e.g. 480x640)
- frames per second (e.g. 25 fps)
- bitrate (e.g. 1Mbit/s)
- codec (e.g. H.264)

**Audio Encoding**

- sample rate (e.g. 44100 Hz)
- bitrate (e.g. 128Kbit/s)
- audio channels (e.g.
  2)
- codec (e.g. AAC)

I hope anyone can help even though this is not necessarily programming related. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much to bobince. That was exactly what I was looking for. I also tried mplayer, but it didn't give me the complete information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most any video demuxer can give you this information. [AVIDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/), [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/), and [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) for example, all have an information mode that dumps the specifics of a video file, including some codec settings.

Comment: avprobe  somemediafile.mp4  # works for most A/V formats